# ionic app - reload is not a function

Tags: ionic-framework, runtime-error, reload

I am not sure how to resolve this one.
the apps runs correctly in the browser, although the preview on iPhone is giving an error :
ay idea on how to resolve this ? thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In ionic 3 when you write (click)="reload()" for any html element then this error comes please check your html template if it has written something like this